# IE7 would not follow JQuery link

Tags: jquery, navigation

IE7 would not follow JQuery link "collateral" and "branding" which are at the bottom of the page. It transitions fine in other versions and browsers.
Here is the code for my JQuery file:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#navWeb').click(function() {
        $('.branding, .collateralT').hide();
        $('.webT').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#navCollateral').click(function() {
        $('.webT, .branding').hide();
        $('.collateralT').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#navBranding').click(function() {
        $('.webT, ul.collateralT').hide();
        $('.branding').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

and here is HTML:

```
<div id="container">
          <nav id="menu">
                <section id="contact">
                    240 481 6963<br>
                    <a href="mailto:y.podlesny@gmail.com">y.podlesny@gmail.com</a>
                 </section>
                <section id="resume"><a href="files/yuliyaPodlesnyResume.pdf" target="_blank" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('resume','','img/resumeON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/resumeOFF.jpg" alt="resume" name="resume" width="190" height="32" border="0"></a></section>
                <section id="portfolioMenu">
                    <a href="#" id="navWeb" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('web','','img/webON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/webOFF.jpg" alt="web" name="web" width="85" height="47" border="0"></a>
                    <a href="#" id="navCollateral" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('collateralOFF','','img/collateralON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/collateralOFF.jpg" alt="commateral material" name="collateralOFF" width="190" height="56" border="0"></a>
                    <a href="#" id="navBranding" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('branding','','img/brandingON.jpg',1)" onClick="getElementById('brandingThumbs')"><img src="img/brandingOFF.jpg" alt="Branding" name="branding" width="190" height="53" border="0"></a>
                </section>
         </nav>
            <section id="slideshow">
                <div id="fadeBlock">
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/thisWeekInWashLong.jpg" id="largeImgClicker"><img src="img/thisWeekInWash.jpg" alt="Large image" id="largeImg" popupimg="img/thisWeekInWashLong.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <h2>This Week In Washington</h2>
                  <div class="sc_menu">
                    <ul class="webT" id="webThumbs" input type="image" value="Go">
                      <li><a href="img/thisWeekInWash.jpg" popupimg="img/thisWeekInWashLong.jpg" id="This Week In Washington" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('thisWeekInWash','','img/keyContactThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/keyContactThumbBlur.jpg" alt="This Week In Wash Newsletter" name="thisWeekInWash" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/caissons.jpg" popupimg="img/caissonsLong.jpg" id="Caisson Case Study Discussion Forum" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('caissons','','img/caissonsThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/caissonsThumbBlur.jpg" name="caissons" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/asceSite.jpg" popupimg="img/asceSiteLong.jpg" id="ASCE Home Page" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('asceHomePage','','img/asceWebThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/asceWebThumbBlur.jpg" alt="ASCE Home Page" name="asceHomePage" width="126" height="82"/></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/sustainability.jpg" id="ASCE Committee on Sustainability Site" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('sustainability','','img/sustainabilityThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/sustainabilityThumbBlur.jpg" name="sustainability" alt="ASCE Committee on Sustainability"  width="126" height="82"/></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="webT" id="webThumbs2" input type="image" value="Go">
                      <li><a href="img/outreach.jpg" popupimg="img/outreachEnewsLong.jpg" id="Pre-College Outreach" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('outreach','','img/outreachThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/outreachThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Pre-College Outreach" name="outreach" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/craneSafety.jpg" popupimg="img/craneSafetyLong.jpg" id="Crane Safety Training Site" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('craneSafety','','img/craneThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/craneThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Crane Safety Training Site" name="craneSafety" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/symposium.jpg" id="Aging Buildings Symposium" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('symposium','','img/symposThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/symposThumbBlur.jpg" alt="symposium" name="symposium" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                   </ul>
                    <ul class="collateralT" id="print" input type="image" value="Go">
                      <li><a href="img/mixAnnRep.jpg" id="Mix Annual Report" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('mixAnnRep','','img/mixAnnRepThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/mixAnnRepThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Mix Annual Report" name="mixAnnRep" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/stPoster.jpg" popupimg="img/stPosterLong.gif" id="Student Membership Poster" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('stPoster','','img/stPosterThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/stPosterThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Student Membership Poster" name="stPoster" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/otc.jpg" id="OTC Hall Of Fame Program" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('otc','','img/otcThumbOn.jpg',1)"><img src="img/otcThumbBlur.jpg" alt="OTC Hall Of Fame Program" name="otc" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/stBrochure.jpg" id="ASCE Student Brochure" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('stBrochureStudent B','','img/stBrochureThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/stBrochureThumbBlur.jpg" alt="ASCE Student Brochure" name="stBrochureStudent B" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/mixStand.jpg" popupimg="img/mixStandLong.jpg" id="Art Directed &mdash; MIX Exhibition Stand " onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image26','','img/mixStandThumbBlur.jpg',1)"><img src="img/mixStandThumbOn.jpg" alt="MIX Exhibition Stand" name="Image26" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
<!--                  <li><a href="img/asceMembershipAd.jpg" id="ASCE Student Membership Ad" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('asceMembershipAd','','img/asceMembershipAdThumb.jpg',1)" onClick="fade('fadeBlock');"><img src="img/asceMembershipAdON.jpg" alt="ASCE Student Membership Ad" name="asceMembershipAd" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="collateralT" input type="image" value="Go">
                      <li><a href="img/keyContact.jpg" id="Key Contact Promotional Package" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('keyContact','','img/keyContactPrintThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/keyContactPrintThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Key Contact Promotional Package" name="keyContact" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/chocolatStand.jpg" id="ChocolatFL Exibition Stand" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('chocolatFL','','img/chocolatflThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/chocolatflThumbBlur.jpg" alt="ChocolatFL Exibition Both" name="chocolatFL" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/insa.jpg" id="INSA Folder With Letterhead" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('insa','','img/insaThumbON.gif',1)"><img src="img/insaThumbBlur.jpg" alt="INSA Folder With Letterhead" name="insa" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/tribe.jpg" popupimg="img/tribeLong.gif" id="Indian Tribes Exhibition Stands " onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('tribe','','img/tribeThumbON.jpg',1)"><img src="img/tribeThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Indian Tribes Exhibition Stands" name="tribe" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="branding" input type="image" value="Go">
                      <li><a href="img/clarksFarm.gif" id="Clark's Farm Logo" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('farm','','img/farmThumbON.gif',1)"><img src="img/farmThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Clark's Farm " name="farm" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/failingInfr.gif" id="Our Critical Infrastructure Logo" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('infr','','img/infrThumbON.gif',1)"><img src="img/infrThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Our Critical Infrastructure Logo" name="infr" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/waterRes.gif" id="Water Resources Coalition Logo" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('water','','img/waterResThumbON.gif',1)"><img src="img/waterResThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Water Resources Coalition" name="water" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="img/bas.gif" id="Bounds Appraisal Services Logo" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('bas','','img/basThumbsON.gif',1)"><img src="img/basThumbsBlur.jpg" alt="Bounds Appraisal Services" name="bas" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="branding">
                      <li><a href="img/jc.gif" id="Job Continent Logo" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('jc','','img/jcThumbON.gif',1)"><img src="img/jcThumbBlur.jpg" alt="Job Continent Logo" name="jc" width="126" height="82" border="0"></a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
            </section>
</div>
    enter code here
```

Comment: If you can pare down your code a bit more to the relevant sections, I think you would get more responses, and faster.

Comment: instead of worrying about your hides and fadeIns - what if you just do a simple alert('something') inside your clicks - just to know if you're getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Several people have reported issues in IE7, and most are related to the way is used the `document.ready` feature of jQuery. IE has different behaviour with it. Try changing your JS code:

```
$(function () {
 $('#navWeb').click(function() {
     $('.branding, .collateralT').hide();
     $('.webT').fadeIn();
 });
 $('#navCollateral').click(function() {
     $('.webT, .branding').hide();
     $('.collateralT').fadeIn();
 });
 $('#navBranding').click(function() {
     $('.webT, ul.collateralT').hide();
     $('.branding').fadeIn();
 });
});
```

To:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  myInit();
});

function myInit() {
 $('#navWeb').click(function() {
     $('.branding, .collateralT').hide();
     $('.webT').fadeIn();
 });
 $('#navCollateral').click(function() {
     $('.webT, .branding').hide();
     $('.collateralT').fadeIn();
 });
 $('#navBranding').click(function() {
     $('.webT, ul.collateralT').hide();
     $('.branding').fadeIn();
 });
}
```